# Hiding/ Securing Apache Beam Dataflow Options in GCP UI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm tinkering with an Apache Beam pipeline on Google Cloud Dataflow and ran into a little issue. I'm passing some sensitive stuff like CloudSQL PostgreSQL DB credentials as Apache Beam options, and I just noticed they're plain visible in the GCP UI.

I want to keep things secure but still be able to use different passwords and credentials for dev and prod. Any best practices in Apache Beam or Google Cloud Dataflow to keep these secrets safe in the UI?

Thinking about:

```
Google Cloud Secret Manager or Cloud KMS for CloudSQL:
   Wanted to know if you integrations supporting CloudSQL, KMS and Apache beam. Any examples also would be appreciated. 

Dataflow Runtime Parameters:
    Any way to specific if runtime options can be hidden in UI? 

Environment Variables:
    Are there any specific considerations or best practices when using environment variables in a Dataflow pipeline? Are those best options to pass these credentials. 

Service Account Permissions:
    Is it possible to use Service Account level permission to use IAM roles to directly access the CloudSQL DB via Default authentication without passing any DB creds?
```

Comment: If you use Java, you could try https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/options/Hidden.html. I am not sure it works.
for env variables, do not use them since they are not passed into the runtime env unless you create your own custom container with these envs.
I think IAM should be a good way to go: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/iam-authentication

Answer (score 0):

The best practice on GCP in general is to use the [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs) for such cases. It allows you to store and manage your secrets across all applications you are building on GCP - not only Dataflow. Furthermore, you can manage and those secrets and their access permissions via Terraform.

In order to access those secrets from within Dataflow, you need to give the Dataflow service account access permission on the secret (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control)). Afterwards, you simply call it using the API of your choice, e.g. [here](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries#use).